# What is the word used to express "investigating someone without their knowledge"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What I mean is this. Police suspects someone living at a house is running an illegal operation from there. So, they mount a base on a house across the street and from there they observe the suspect, take pictures, etc. The operation can be simple as two cops on a car, from a distance, observing the suspect, 24h.

How do you say:

> the cops are doing a _________________ operation

I am talking about the act of doing it hidden.

For example, you have **sting** operations, where you deploy a bait car to catch thieves, or an **undercover** operation where you infiltrate a gang, for example. What about this kind of hidden observing a suspect?

I am sure I have heard that a million times on movies, but I cannot remember.

Comment: in a hidden manner or way.

Comment: Why is "surveillance" not the Answer? What research did you do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe "clandestine" or "covert" operation, for adjectives, or "surveillance", using that noun as an adjective.

Comment: No, police do not surveil covertly or clandestinely. Spies engage is covert or clandestine activities.

Comment: @Lambie: In the real world, US police do a lot of spying.  See for instance "undercover cop", "wiretap", and similar terms.  Heck, even that cop (or perhaps multiple cops) I see hanging out behind a hill is doing covert surveillance.

Comment: @jamesqf Of course they do but a base across the street in American English is not called clandestine or covert. For pete's sake...It is called undercover surveillance or a stakeout.  Cops may engage in spying but generally spying is between countries. Anyone can **spy on** anyone,right?

Comment: @Lambie: I think you are trying to split hairs here.  There are many forms of covert surveillance, and US cops use most of them.  I'm not arguing about exactly what engaging in surveillance from "a base across the street" is called .  I simply commented on your absurd claim that police don't do it, whatever it might be called.

Comment: @Lambie "generally spying is between countries" No. A spouse can spy on their husband if they suspect an affair. Industrial espionage where companies spy on each other to gain their secrets is a big thing. parents sometimes spy on their children. And of couse cops sometimes spy ... covertly, as I may add.

Comment: NYPD has an Intelligence and CounterTerrorism Department. They most are most definitely a spy organization.

Comment: +1 for surveillance.  That's really the best answer here, for police work in US common parlance.  "We have him under surveillance."  "There is a surveillance operation at that site."

Comment: @jamesqf  Never mind. Police do a lot of "spying" but they don't use that word among themselves. I spend a lot of time reading, and watching police procedurals (UK and US and AUS and NZ and even CANADA) and the term spying is used by others ABOUT cops but not by THEM. Geesus. The main term is **undercover** and/or "surveillance" (operation), not covert  and not certainly not clandestine.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm not sure just how accurately police procedurals represent the behavior of real cops.  I'm not a fan of the genre, but I expect that a good many are written/produced for an audience that wants to see the police presented as heros, so they call police activities by terms that are more socially acceptable.  So you're correct about different words being used, depending on who is describing the activity.

Comment: @jamesqf How other than via books, articles and TV shows can one know what is used? Only that way. Ergo, if you don't "do" those, then, you wouldn't know, in fact.

Comment: @Lambie: Err,,, Because I know English?  We may be talking past each other here: as I said, I don't know much about cop jargon, or what they call their spying in order to make it seem more palatable.  I just know the normal English terms for such behavior.

Answer (score 18):

A [stakeout](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stakeout) is defined as "a surveillance maintained by the police of an area or a person suspected of criminal activity."

You do not use it in combination with the word "operation" - it is a noun in its own right.  So you would say, "The cops are doing a **stakeout**."

Comment: Or you verb it and just say that the cops are "staking out" 1234 Any St.

Comment: @BillBarth - Note that you added an object that wasn't in the original sentence, since the phrasal verb **stake out** is always transitive.

Comment: OK, so you rewrite your sentence/paragraph a bit to include the object since the original question contemplated a location.

Answer (score 9):

In the U.S. they would be working *undercover* and you could say, *The cops are engaged in **undercover** surveillance*.  Clandestine and covert also work but I think *undercover* is most often used to describe police activities.

Comment: Undercover means that the investigator becomes a member of the group they're investigating, without revealing that they're in law enforcement. It doesn't refer to observing at a distance.

Comment: @Barmar You are correct.  This journal's summary seems to address some of the OP's questions. https://www.ncjrs.gov/App/Publications/abstract.aspx?ID=92672

Answer (score 5):

The "base in a house across the street" is called a [stakeout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeout_(disambiguation)).

Comment: I feel like a stakeout is often waiting for a suspect to arrive, then grabbing them,

Comment: @OwenReynolds No, that's an ambush. The intent of a stakeout is purely surveillance (which may naturally lead to an arrest or confrontation later based on the evidence acquired).

Comment: Say the cops think a murder suspect might show up at his girlfriend's house. The chief doesn't say "do an ambush", they say "stake out her place".

Answer (score 1):

This would be called "surveillance", officially - or "stakeout" as slang.

In that case, the police would "be undercover", but that doesn't fit the clue, as it would be "*an* undercover operation".

Comment: "Stakeout" is US slang as well, I'm not aware of the term in an Australian context, only from US movies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply state:

> “…the cops are doing a secret operation…”

Also, keep in mind language should change if the circumstances don’t include a public law enforcement authority. Such as if I were to do a personal investigation without letting anyone know I would describe it as follows:

> “…he is doing his own personal operation…”

Or this:

> “…he is doing his own private operation…”

Context and who is doing it determines language used. Police would never do something in a “personal” or “private” way like this. Their operations will always be non-personal (they are doing their job) and would not be private (they are in public service).

But that said if some police are doing unofficial investigations/operations — something that would get them in trouble if higher ups in the department learned about it — it could be described as:

> “…the cops are doing an unsanctioned operation…”